# UIAlertView title set sending "SIGABRT"

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4, uialertview

I'm new to Cocoa Touch and I'm just messing around trying to get a feel for the language and framework. So I'm just trying to create a simple app that takes text from a `UITextField` and just shows it in a `UIAlertView` here is the action method:

```
- (IBAction)showNotifAction:(id)sender {
    putVal = _TextToDisplay.text;
    _alertOne.title = @"Message";
    _alertOne.message = putVal;
    [_alertOne show];
}
```

For some reason it breaks on line 3 with a SIGART. Is there something I'm doing wrong? Oh, BTW, here is my `AppDelegate` implementation:

```
@interface LearnAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UITextField *_TextToDisplay;
    UIButton *_ShowNotif;    
    UIAlertView *_alertOne;
    NSString *putVal;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your UIAlertVIew. Pointer that you are trying to use points to nothing or to garbaged memory.

Try something like the following code:

```
    UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:"My title" 
message:putVal
delegate:nil 
cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];
    [alert show];
```